# if you create a variables in a function, are they automatically localised to that particular thread running it?

Tags: python, multithreading

If you have a function which creates variables from values(associated to variables outside of the function) are these new variables localised to the particular thread running the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about [*local variables?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) I don't know the exact details of how Python is implemented, but conceptually, Every time a function is called, an [*activation record*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#ACTIVATION-RECORD) (AR) is created. The AR is a data structure that contains the arguments, and all of the local variables for that one specific call. The AR is destroyed when the call for which it was created returns.

That means, not only do concurrent calls to the same function in different threads each have their own AR, but also; if there are recursive calls to the function in the *same* thread, those calls also each have their own AR containing their own private versions of the local variables.

---

P.S.; Don't forget though, that a variable is not the same thing as an object. Objects in Python (including tuples, lists, dictionaries, etc. as well as program-defined `class` objects) don't live in variables at all. They only exist on the [*heap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP), and when we say that such-and-such variable "contains" an object, that's a lazy way of saying that the variable [*refers to*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) the object.

It often can happen that local variables from two or more different activation records will refer to the same shared object.

Comment: CPython uses the term "Stack Frame" for what you're calling an Activation Record. You can introspect the call stack with some of the methods in the `inspect` module.

Comment: The linked article also primarily uses the term "stack frame".

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, to summerise what you are saying, when a thread targets a function, when that particular function formulates a value/ creates an object and assigns it to a variable. Then that variable will be localised to that particular thread because of the "stack framing"? Therefore, other threads will not alter each other's variable within that targetted function?

Comment: Re, "stack frame" vs. "activation record." IMO they both mean the same thing, but I prefer to say "stack frame" when I am talking about implementation details, and I say "activation record" when I am deliberately trying to avoid implementation details, and only speak in terms of how some programming language is defined.

Comment: @AndrewE, If some function creates some object, uses the object, and does _not_ store a reference to the object in any other place besides one of its own local variables, then no other thread (or recursive activation of the function in the same thread) will be able to access the object, and the object will be deleted (garbage collected) when the function returns.